# Does IntelliJ treat .py files differently from .txt files when they are created

Tags: python, file, intellij-idea, ide

I accidentally created a new .txt file when I wanted a .py file. Of course, Run doesn't work. But, it made me wonder what is happening inside of IntelliJ when I create a .py file, compared to when I create a .txt file.

Here are some possibilities I considered:

1. Is there hidden code in the file itself? Seems unlikely because then there would have to be cleanup before committing.
2. Is there a table of some kind inside IntelliJ that it uses to decide what to render on the screen and what functions to make available?
3. Is there some other structure involved that I haven't thought of?

Comment: I have no idea but a simple way to do it would just be to check the extension of the file.. unless I missunderstood the question?

Comment: I'm more wondering what the internal structure is that IntelliJ uses. I'm guessing that there is something that happens when you create the file that is more than adding an extension, but it could be as simple as that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JetBrains IDEs determine the file type from the filename or hashbang line by default. But if you right-click on the filename in the project, you can use **Override file type** to change the type of that file.

You can go into **Preferences->Editor->File Types** to edit the correspondence between filename patterns and types.

So click on the `.txt` file and set its type to "Python script".

Answer (score 1):

There is no hidden code or special internal structure within the file itself. The IDE relies on file extensions and possibly content inspection to determine the appropriate language and corresponding features.